# typescript import from <variable> instead of literal string?

Tags: angular, typescript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Is it possible in Typescript to dynamically set the from path into a variable when importing?

Eg turn this:

```
import {HomeComponent} from './dashboard/home/home.component';
```

To something like this:

```
let hompageComponentPath = './dashboard/home/home.component';
import * from hompageComponentPath;
```

Comment: Have you tried that exact thing?

Comment: it was the first thing i did... :)  "] ERROR in ./script/core/app.module.ts
[1] (62,42): error TS1141: String literal expected."

Comment: Try this: declare var require: any; let hompageComponentPath = './dashboard/home/home.component'; let importedModule = require(hompageComponentPath );

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## With the dynamic `import` proposal

There is [a proposal for dynamic import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) in ECMAScript.

[Since TypeScript 2.4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/06/27/announcing-typescript-2-4/#dynamic-import-expressions), dynamic `import` expressions are available. Here is an example:

```
async function getZipFile(name: string, files: File[]): Promise<File> {
    const zipUtil = await import('./utils/create-zip-file');
    const zipContents = await zipUtil.getAsBlob(files);
    return new File(zipContents, name);
}
```

The `import`, used as a function, returns a promise which can be awaited.

## ... But not with the ES6 static `import` / `export`

It's not possible to do that with the syntax `import` / `export` because the ES6 standard had explicitly defined modules in a static way.

From the article [ES6 In Depth: Modules](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/):

> For a dynamic language, JavaScript has gotten itself a surprisingly static module system.
>
> - All flavors of `import` and `export` are allowed only at toplevel in a module. There are no conditional imports or exports, and you can’t use `import` in function scope.
> - All exported identifiers must be explicitly exported by name in the source code. You can’t programmatically loop through an array and export a bunch of names in a data-driven way.
> - Module objects are frozen. There is no way to hack a new feature into a module object, polyfill style.
> - All of a module’s dependencies must be loaded, parsed, and linked eagerly, before any module code runs. There’s no syntax for an `import` that can be loaded lazily, on demand.
> - There is no error recovery for `import` errors. An app may have hundreds of modules in it, and if anything fails to load or link, nothing runs. You can’t import in a `try/catch` block. (The upside here is that because the system is so static, webpack can detect those errors for you at compile time.)
> - There is no hook allowing a module to run some code before its dependencies load. This means that modules have no control over how their dependencies are loaded.

Comment: Actually there is newer proposal that's being worked on now: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import

Comment: dynamic import has been implemented. See [import() - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import "import() - JavaScript | MDN")

Answer (score 3):

You can use `import` as a function and then pass any dynamically created string rather than a string literal.

This returns a Promise though so keep in mind that it needs to be run within an async function rather than at the very top of the file.

eg.

```
async main(): Promise<void> { 

        const  myData = await import(`../../data/${environment.theme}/chapters`);
        
        console.log({ myData });
}
```